# VS 2010 constantly crashing with System.AggregateException after installing Visual Studio Async CTP

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My VS2010 was rock solid until I made a mistake of installing [Visual Studio Async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9983)... after that it started crashing all the time and continued crashing even after I uninstalled the CTP, uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio, and eventhough I do not have any PLINQ in my code...

Note that Problem Signature 09 below and the related `System.AggregateException`...

> AggregateException is used to consolidate multiple failures into a
>   single, throwable exception object. It is used extensively in the Task
>   Parallel Library and Parallel LINQ (PLINQ). For an example, see How
>   to: Handle Exceptions Thrown by Tasks and How to: Handle Exceptions in
>   a PLINQ Query.

Just wondering if anyone else experienced similar problems and maybe found a solution?

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 10.0.40219.1
  Problem Signature 03: 4d5f2a73
  Problem Signature 04: System.Data.Entity
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ba1e2fd
  Problem Signature 07: 1a09
  Problem Signature 08: 6d
  Problem Signature 09: System.AggregateException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1033
```

Answer (score 2):

A co-worker hit the same problem today. Considering that re-installation on your side didn't help I tried the following:

I removed the following folders (renamed them actually, as a quick backup):

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Visual Studio\10.0 
<MyDocuments>\Visual Studio 2010
```

It starts up fine after that. We haven't isolated what in those per-user setting folders caused the problem, but at least you'll be able to continue working.

Comment: I really believe you just need to take out all the per-user/per-machine settings. Make a backup folder and move all VisualStudio/10.0 folders you can find in there. There are VisualStudio folders under All Users\AppData, <Username>\AppData\Microsoft and under <Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft etc. Maybe even do a search.

Answer (score 1):

When you uninstall Async CTP, there are usually a minimum of 2 uninstalls that need run (I had 4 on my machine). There is one per version of Visual Studio on your machine, and I believe at least 1 uninstall under the .Net Framework.

Make sure you have `Show Updates` on and remove all instances of it that you can find. Also, I know there is `AsyncCTP Refresh` for use with VS2010 SP1, and using the regular `AsyncCTP` library with SP1 will cause problems.

I'm not sure if it will help, but the Version #s shown in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/13/async-ctp-refresh-installation.aspx) helped me when I was having trouble with the AsyncCTP installation

Also, I believe you can only have one CTP library installed at any time, so if you use another CTP library you cannot use the Async one as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but there is nothing in my installed programs or updates containing the keyword 'Async'. I also checked the version numbers of my csc.exe and msvbide.dll and these do not correspond to the version numbers listed in the link you provided...

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure; but I think your best step now is to repair your Visual Studio 2010 installation. Takes a while; but you'll probably spend more time trying to find the mouse in the walls rather than just knocking the whole house down.

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed VS 2010 and re-applied the SP1 and none of that helped... it appears that CTP left some junk behind but I can't figure out what and where...